# Can I use multigrid to solve linear algebra problems that do not arise from a differential equation?

Tags: multigrid

Can the Multigrid method be applied to solve a linear system of equations in the form $Ax=b$, that is not necessarily related to differential equations?

Answer (score 6):

There are "Algebraic Multigrid Methods" that can be applied to general systems $Ax=b$.

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric positive definite (SPD), is it possible to use the AMG method as a preconditioner for the conjugate gradient method?

Comment: Yes, you could try AMG as a preconditioner.